# How can i remove links for digits from my file using perl?

Tags: perl

---

Here is the part of code which i studied from the stack overflow website and tried implementing the same for my code too.But i am not getting  the expected one.

Here in code i tried  to remove the href links for digits from my files using perl module HTML::TreeBuilder.

This is my part of subroutine which i tried to remove hyperlinks for all digits.

```
sub process_file
{
print "enter";
my ($files)=@_;
print "******$files**********";
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($files);
foreach my $a ($root->find_by_tag_name('a')) {
    if ($a->attr('href') =~ /^\d+/) {
       $a->replace_with_content($a->as_text);
#print $a;
    }
}
print $root->as_HTML(undef, "\t");
}
```

Code Explanation:

1.This subroutine is used to remove the hyperlinks in the files.In my files all numbers are hyperlinked.So i tried  to remove it.

2.Foreach is looking for  href tags.

3.Next in if condition i tried to match the digits in the file.

Input file snippet:[version*.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svIfz.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  
Wat do you mean by "links for digits"? What are you trying to achieve? What is the code you copied doing? What do you want to change in behaviour?  What exactly did you change in the code? What do you mean by "expected one"? What is the unwanted behaviour you observe? Do you get and warnings/errors? Do you use `use strict; usewarnings`?  Use formatting.

Comment: Here added only my subroutine part.I My code is running well until the print statement which i had given inside the code.The theme of the subroutine is to remove hyperlinks for all digits because in my file only the  digits are hyperlinked .So i had tried to remove it. @Yunnosch

Comment: Tell me more about it.

Comment: What type of file is it for the Input. Can you please post a small input snippet for better understanding.

Comment: sure will post my snippet. @Mohit

Comment: i had added input snippet please look into it . @Mohit

Comment: from the snippet i need to remove hyperlinks from the first column (i.e only from digits) .@Mohit

Comment: In my code i had tried to remove hyperlinks via parsing module i.e.tree builder .And $files will shift the files .@Yunnosch

Comment: The [previous question about this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159328/sed-command-fails-to-remove-hyperlinked-contents-from-my-html-files-using-perl/) was asked by a user called [in site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8058695/in-site). Why have you changed your username?

Comment: The input file you have shown is is an image of rendered HTML. How is that useful to us? We need to see the raw input - the actual HTML. And we need to see it as text, so we can copy it into files so that we can test your code and our fixes. Why would you think that a picture of text is useful to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. The only thing missing is that you are not writing the modified contents back to your file. PFB the updated code for that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

print "enter";
my ($files)= "abc.html";
print "******$files**********\n";
my $FileFH;
my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($files);
foreach my $a ($root->find_by_tag_name('a')) {
    if ($a->attr('href') =~ /^\d+/) {
       $a->replace_with_content($a->as_text) or die "Cannot replace";
    }
}
print $root->as_HTML(undef, "\t");

open($FileFH,'>',$files);
print $FileFH $root->as_HTML(undef, "\t");
print "File Written successfully";
```